# How to use reftex in multiple files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, include, reftex

I tried some solutions but fail so far. 
I divide large data into multiple files and then include all of them in main file. I used emacs24. Here is general of my main.tex file

```
\include{chapter1}
\section{test} hello POS
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{mybibliography}
```

In the main.tex file, I enabled reftext-mode, and then ctrl+c+[, the reftex works for me and it asks me to type searched word for bibliography.

However, this operation fail when I switch to the chaper1.tex buffer, the error message is:

```
 **byte-code: No valid bibliography in this document, and no default available**
```

The chaper1.tex is like:

```
\section{introduce}
....
\subsection{result}
```

Clearly, the error message shows that chapter1.tex does not contain any `\bibliography{mybibliography}`, which already is in `main.tex`.

Since I do not want add any `\bibliography` in my `chapter1.tex`, how should I handle this error?

================================================

**UPDATE:**
I also followed page: https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html and tried the two solutions given below:

SOLUTION 1: Add these to `.emacs`/`init.el` file

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
```

OR
 SOLUTION 2: Add these declarations at beginning of each file

```lisp
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-parse-self: t
%%% TeX-auto-save: t
%%% End:
```

After restarting emacs and  reenabling `reftex-mode` in chapter1.tex,  the problem still occurs.

Comment: Are you using AUCTeX? If so, did you enable file parsing?

Comment: @giordano:  Yes. I use AUCTEX. I have update but still fail. How to enable file parse?

Comment: It's described in the very first lines of the [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html), see the sentence "If you want to make AUCTeX aware of style files and multi-file documents right away, insert the following in your `.emacs` file.".  Guido's answer explain how to manually fix the problem for a single file, but adding those lines to your init file you'll be always automatically prompt for selecting the master file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a master file (`main.tex`). Thus you can include the following in all `.tex` files in your project.

```lisp
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "main"
%%% End:
```

After that, reftex will find the bibliography from the master (`main.tex`) file.

Comment: `main` and `Main` are two different files `;-)`

Comment: Thanks @giordano. The Tex-master points to the main.tex file and then reftex works.

Comment: After inserting the above Local Variables, typing `C-c C-n`(CTRL+C and afterwards CTRL+n) will reread the configuration data, it found four your master document `main.tex`.  From the manual `Remove all information about this buffer, and apply the style hooks again.`